# React Native: get available height

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to get the available height between the top and bottom elements. Currently, I am calculating it by 
`screenHeight - statusBarHeight - topElementHeight - bottomElementHeight`.

[image: visualization of the layout]

This method is working, but I always have to look up if all the top and bottom elements are visible and account for that.
Is there any better method of getting this height?

Comment: have you tried using flexbox? is a good way to not need to use height on everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a View element in between top and bottom elements and use [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout) prop to receive dimensions of this View.

```
    render() {
       <TopComponent />
       <View onLayout={this.measureView} />
       <BottomComponent />
    }

    measureView = (event) => {
       console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)
    }
```

Make sure that the View occupies the entire space between top and bottom elements. You can use flexbox or absolute positioning for that depending on your current layout.

Comment: how would I calculate it on `componentWillMount`?

Comment: The calculations are not ready when`componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` is called. But `measureView` is called right after `componentDidMount` so you can put any logic involving view height right into `measureView`.